# JPA insert data to H2 database

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa, h2

I'm trying to add some data to H2 database via JPA. I see a lot of materials where they use javax.persistence unfortunately when I download JPA starter I don't have this package. I use jakarta.persistance and it's generate me the empty table but when I add to resource folder data.sql file with insert command (insert into person (name) values("jan")) I have nothing to add.

Below @SpringBootAplication:

```
package com.example.jpa.database.jpadatabase;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class JpadatabaseApplication  {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(JpadatabaseApplication.class, args);
    }



}
```

and POJO class

```
package com.example.jpa.database.jpadatabase;



import jakarta.persistence.Entity;
import jakarta.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import jakarta.persistence.GenerationType;
import jakarta.persistence.Id;
import jakarta.persistence.Table;



@Entity(name="Person")
@Table(name="Person")
public class Person   {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private int id;
    private String name;


    public Person() {
      
    }

    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;

    }

    public Person(int id, String name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Person [id=" + id + ", name=" + name + "]";
    }



  
}
```

also my application.properties

```
spring.datasource.driver-class-name = org.h2.Driver

spring.h2.console.enable=true

spring.datasource.url=jdbc:h2:mem:testdb
```

and sql insert into person (name) values("jan");

Below is the error:

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the condition evaluation report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2023-02-12T13:18:43.516+01:00 ERROR 73739 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/sql/init/DataSourceInitializationConfiguration.class]: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/janhandzel/Developer/Kurs%20IBM%20/database-jpa/jpadatabase/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into person (name) values("jan")
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1751) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:599) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:521) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:326) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:324) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:313) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:200) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1130) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:905) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:584) ~[spring-context-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:432) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1302) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1291) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at com.example.jpa.database.jpadatabase.JpadatabaseApplication.main(JpadatabaseApplication.java:12) ~[classes/:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) ~[spring-boot-devtools-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
Caused by: org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptStatementFailedException: Failed to execute SQL script statement #1 of URL [file:/Users/janhandzel/Developer/Kurs%20IBM%20/database-jpa/jpadatabase/target/classes/data.sql]: insert into person (name) values("jan")
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:282) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ResourceDatabasePopulator.populate(ResourceDatabasePopulator.java:254) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.DatabasePopulatorUtils.execute(DatabasePopulatorUtils.java:54) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.boot.jdbc.init.DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(DataSourceScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:87) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.runScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:146) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:108) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.applyDataScripts(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:102) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.initializeDatabase(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:77) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.boot.sql.init.AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractScriptDatabaseInitializer.java:66) ~[spring-boot-3.0.2.jar:3.0.2]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1797) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1747) ~[spring-beans-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        ... 23 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Table "PERSON" not found (this database is empty); SQL statement:
insert into person (name) values("jan") [42104-214]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:199) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8385) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.getTableOrViewNotFoundDbException(Parser.java:8369) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8358) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableOrView(Parser.java:8328) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parseInsert(Parser.java:1632) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:814) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:237) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:223) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:94) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-5.0.1.jar:na]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.init.ScriptUtils.executeSqlScript(ScriptUtils.java:261) ~[spring-jdbc-6.0.4.jar:6.0.4]
        ... 33 common frames omitted
```

Comment: So do you get an error when you run the application?

Comment: See: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-data-sql-and-schema-sql

Comment: maybe depend on repository or service or resource layers, would you please share these layers?

Comment: Side note: "_... `javax.persistence` ... I don't have this package._" - Yes, the use of `javax.persistence` is still around (especially in tutorials), but it is older/outdated. See [Transition from Java EE to Jakarta EE](https://blogs.oracle.com/javamagazine/post/transition-from-java-ee-to-jakarta-ee).

Comment: @Youans I just added to the post the error stack-trace

Comment: try to remove the `@Table` annotation, just keep the `@Entity`, but also remove the parameter `name` and its value from the `@Entity` declaraion.

Comment: @cyberbrain Unfortunately it does not help. Still have the same error... Strange is that if I remove the data.sql file, Spring will create an empty table, but when I add the data.sql file it shows that the table is not created.....

Comment: You didn't mention a *data.sql* file in your setup before - please add details about to to the question.

Comment: @cyberbrain in data.sql I have only one sql line "insert into person (name) values("jan");" nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The presence of your `data.sql` file disables the schema creation by Hibernate, because it is assumed that you manually want to create the schema via a `schema.sql` as well.

If you want Hibernates schema generation but want to add data with a script, [the documentation has the following advice](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#howto.data-initialization.using-basic-sql-scripts):

> Script-based DataSource initialization is performed, by default, before any JPA EntityManagerFactory beans are created. schema.sql can be used to create the schema for JPA-managed entities and data.sql can be used to populate it. While we do not recommend using multiple data source initialization technologies, if you want script-based DataSource initialization to be able to build upon the schema creation performed by Hibernate, set spring.jpa.defer-datasource-initialization to true. This will defer data source initialization until after any EntityManagerFactory beans have been created and initialized. schema.sql can then be used to make additions to any schema creation performed by Hibernate and data.sql can be used to populate it.